# ImportError: libta_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu

i'm trying to import talib, but I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: libta_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I start python like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" python
```

import talib works.

How can I turn this solution into a fixed one?

Comment: That's a system administration problem, not a software development one. (In general, `/etc/ld.so.conf` can be modified to adjust the paths that are searched, and `ldconfig` invoked to check the path). See [Where do executables look for shared objects at runtime?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime) on [unix.se] (where this question would be much more on-topic).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue. See below for what I did to fix it.

installing

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib/
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
Sudo make install
pip install numpy
```

If you don't have it installed

```
pip install TA-Lib
```

if you do have it installed

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall TA-Lib
```

hope this helps someone :)

Comment: `--prefix=/usr` means you're installing software in a region reserved for use by your operating system's package manager. It *works*, sure, but it'll cause trouble later -- means an attempt to install an OS package for the same software would fail unless forced, for example. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux/8658 for discussion.

Comment: Does it matter in which directory you wget ?

Comment: @Fredovsky no it doesn't, that just dictates the location which you're downloading the `tar.gz` to.

Answer (score 15):

add the foldername to ldconfig:

```
sudo -s 
echo "include /usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
ldconfig
```

Answer (score 11):

For me, following worked:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

1. put above line to `/etc/ld.so.conf`
2. execute `sudo ldconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

You may well find that ldconfig is already configured to search '/usr/local/lib', and in this case, you only need to reload it, using `sudo ldconfig`.

(I would post this as a comment, but insufficient reputation.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are arriving at this Stack Overflow question and you're working with  shared libraries that are being cross compiled for different platforms/architectures, consider that you might be trying to access a shared object that was compiled for another platform by mistake.

I was getting this error while building my own shared libraries on a `darwin/arm64` system for a `linux/amd64` docker container. **After rebuilding my shared libraries while being careful to build for the right architecture, I no longer received the `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error** and my shared library was accessible to my python application.